# LoadRunner "Cannot start recording" for SAP GUI

Tags: loadrunner, sap-gui

I am attempting to create a LoadRunner vuser script of SAP GUI. However, I am consistently getting an error stating

> the recording could not be started

Below are the steps I am following to attempt to create a recording. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to SAP GUI and LoadRunner.

I am using

- HP Virtual User Generator 11.00.0.0
- SAP NetWeaver v7200.3.11.1074

Steps:

1. Select SAP GUI protocol and click 'Create'
2. Set the program to record and working directory then click 'OK'

   - Application type: Win32 Applications
   - Program to record: SAP Logon
   - Program arguments:
   - Working directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui`
   - Record into Action: Action

Result:

A window appears stating that the application is being launched for recording immediately followed by an error stating that the recording could not be started.

Does anyone one know what could potentially be causing this type of issue?

Is there any log file I can watch to get more specific information regarding the cause of this issue?

Any other troubleshooting steps I could take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your tips. I managed to identify my particular problem. In the windows event log I noticed that a service named "Avecto Privilege Guard Service" was kicking off every time SapGuiRecord.exe would run.

I stopped the service from the task manager and my recording problem is solved.

Hopefully this might be a clue for anyone else who might encounter a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Time to go back to the installation requirements, including your credentials on the box.   95% ++ of the time when you cannot record the reason is due to one or more of the installation requirements not having been met.   This is where to start and eliminate any issues here before going further.

By the way, this is not just LoadRunner, this is for any performance testing tool

Comment: Thank you for your comment James. I am able to create/record other types of scripts using the Web (HTTP/HTML) protocol. So I am reasonably sure LoadRunner is installed correctly. Would you happen to know if there are any particular installation requirements to use the SAPGUI protocol?

Comment: Read the section in the manuals on the SAP virtual users in the VUGEN development guide.   Any preconditions should be noted there.    JUst because you can record web does not mean that all of the preconditions for installation have been fully satisfied.